# Curl download have output fopen script

Tags: php, curl, fopen

I want to download file via `FTP` with `curl`. It's done but it returns output string. How do i remove it?
There's the output :

> -rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 50266 Dec 18 10:38 jkegiatan10.jpg -rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 158392 Dec 18 09:45 jkegiatan19.jpg -rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 50266
>   Dec 18 10:38 jkegiatan10.jpg -rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 158392 Dec 18 09:45
>   jkegiatan19.jpg -rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 50266 Dec 18 10:38
>   jkegiatan10.jpg -rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 158392 Dec 18 09:45
>   jkegiatan19.jpg

The code :
        `set_time_limit(0);
        $fp = fopen ($dwnpath, 'wb') ;
        $ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));`

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp) ; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
    return $filename;</code>
```

Thanks so much,
Regards

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve here and how you're doing it. Do you mind supplying some code and emphasising the needed outcome?

Comment: here's the code :
 set_time_limit(0);
        $fp = fopen ($dwnpath, 'wb') ;
        $ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp) ;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

        curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
        return $filename;

Comment: Update your question instead!